# How to assign a UNIX variable in bash with html file contents?

Tags: html, unix

I have a html file and I am copying the contents to a variable in bash as MAILLOG=$(cat mail). The html file donot have any quotes in it. When assignment is made it throws error for < , /, {. Error No such file or directory is thrown

Answer (score 0):

You still need to wrap the variable in " so that it is handled as text and not trying to parse the < and > brackets.

```
MAILLOG="$(cat mail)"
```